# getgrnam() causing error for no apparent reason?

Tags: c, linux

I am getting an error that makes no sense. I have the following code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>

gid_t groupIdFromName(const char *name)
{
    struct group *grp;
    gid_t g;
    char *endptr;

    if (name == NULL || *name == '\0')
        return -1;

    g = strtol(name, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr == '\0')
        return g;

    grp = getgrnam(name);
    if (grp == NULL)
        return -1;

    return grp->gr_gid;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I am using NetBeans in Linux Mint and when I try and while my program builds without problems, when I try and run it I get the following error -

```
Signal received: SIGSEGV (?) with sigcode ? (?)
From process: ?
```

If I comment out the line `grp = getgrnam(name);` this error goes away. But I don't understand why this line should cause it to fail, particularly since my main method is blank.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the function groupIdFromName?

Comment: I can compile this program with gcc and run it with no problem.

Comment: The code here just does `return (EXIT_SUCCESS);` in main(). How does the actual code look like ?

Comment: How does the "error go away" by commenting if you're dereferencing an uninitialized `grp` pointer (i.e. `return grp->gr_gid;`)? Surely this must be coincidental.

Comment: At a wild guess, there is something in the environment interfering here - is there an `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_BIND_NOW` set? These can allow a compilation to work, but crash on run-time linking.

Comment: @akluth I am not even calling it. My main method is blank yet when I run the program I get that error.

Comment: @RageD I am not dereferencing an uninitialized pointer because I never even enter the groupIdFromName() function. I realise that the program would fail if I did enter that function once I comment out the line I mentioned.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that I am running Linux Mint on a VMWare Player virtual machine?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are segfaulting in a function that you don't even call???

Comment: @RandyHoward Yes, and its a NetBeans-GDB bug. The same code works fine in Eclipse.

Comment: +1 simply for having the most totally unexpected bug imaginable.

Comment: @RandyHoward 'you are segfaulting in a function that you don't even call' - f*!& my life

Answer (score 0):

I have found that many people have been experiencing this bug for quite some time in NetBeans and Code::Blocks. I tried the code in Eclipse and it works fine. So don't use NetBeans for C development on Linux is my advice.